# SQL union fields in one

Tags: mysql, sql

there is a sample of returns is:

```
  id | value1 | value2
-------------------------
   1 |  AAAA  |  NULL
   2 |  NULL  |  BBBB
   3 |  CCCC  |  DDDD
```

required to get it:

```
  id | value 
--------------
   1 |  AAAA  
   2 |  BBBB  
   3 |  CCCC  
   3 |  DDDD
```

as a way of sql I get it?

Comment: Can you provide how you are selecting the data?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this

```
select Id, value1 from yourtable
Where value1 is not null
Union all
select Id, value2 from yourtable
Where value2 is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work with an `UNION` :

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT col3, col4 FROM table WHERE col4 IS NOT NULL
```

Use an `UNION ALL` if you want to keep duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
insert into #temp (id, value1, value2) values
(1,'AAAA', NULL)
,(2,NULL,'BBBB')
,(3, 'CCCC','DDDD')

select id, value1 as value from #temp where value1 is not null
union all
select id, value2 as value from #temp where value2 is not null
```

Comment: Duplicate of my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is also helpful...for mysql IFNULL and sql-server ISNULL.

```
SELECT id, IFNULL(value1, value2) val1 FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, value2 FROM table1 WHERE value1 IS NOT NULL AND value2 IS NOT NULL
```